# How to center inserted image vertically relative to the line in MS Word?

Tags: microsoft-word, images

I have inserted small image into Word, denoting mobile phone and got the following picture:

[image]

As you see, bottom side of a picture is aligned with bottom side of a line.

Is ti possible to make image centered, like here:

[image]

(made in graphics editor)

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is an automatic 'centered', so you have to do it manually. Probably, the reason is that there is no defined 'center' for a text line - if it has 'WWW', center would be somewhere else than if it has 'ggg'...

Click on the picture once, so it is selected, and then use <kbd>CRSR-UP</kbd> and <kbd>CRSR-DOWN</kbd> to move it; if the steps are to large, use <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>CRSR-UP</kbd> and <kbd>ALT</kbd><kbd>CRSR-DOWN</kbd>.

if you want it very exact, you can zoom in the view before you do that.

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 ways you can do that.  As @Aganju stated you can position the image manually, but there is an automatic way by using tables with no Borders.

To do things manually I use [absolute positioning](http://word.tips.net/T001441_Absolutely_Positioning_a_Graphic.html).  This to me is better as you are in full control of distances between each object.

To do this automatically you could create a 1 row table 2 columns wide and put the image in the left column and the text in the right column, then use [text align within the cells](http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-align-text-in-table-columns-and-rows-in-wor.html).  Provided the image positioning is set to "in line with text" the same method will also automatically centre images vertically.